# Perl - Count occurances of array elements in text file?

Tags: arrays, perl

So I have an array of words (foo, bar, baz, hello) that I want to count the occurances of in another array(foo, foo, bar, bar, bar, baz, baz), then create a hash of the words as keys and the number of occurances as values, if the word cannot be found in the other array the output should be a 0, my code:

```
my @array1 = ("foo","bar", "baz", "hey");
my @array2 = ("foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "baz", "baz");
my %hash;

foreach my $count (@array2){
$hash{$count}++;
}
for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
print "$key = $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

The output of this will be

```
foo = 2
bar = 3
baz = 2
```

How would I use @array1 to count the occurances of its elements in @array2 so that it would provide the output:

```
foo = 2
bar = 3
baz = 2
hey = 0
```

So that I can add new elements to @array1 for future comparison operations? Because my current solution does not scale since the content of @array2 is drawn from a text file.

Comment: Slight typo in your code above: `$hash{$count]++` should be `$hash{$count}++` Note the closing brace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also not manually count in a loop, by using grep to count for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = ("foo","bar", "baz", "hey");
my @array2 = ("foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "baz", "baz");
my %hash;

for my $i (@array1){
$hash{$i}=grep{/^${i}$/} @array2
}

print "Key: $_ and Value: $hash{$_}\n" for (keys%hash);
```

produces

```
Key: bar and Value: 3
Key: baz and Value: 2
Key: hey and Value: 0
Key: foo and Value: 2
```

Comment: That involves unnecessarily looping over all the elements of `@array2` multiple times (within `grep`). Also `$i` is a poor choice of identifier as it is generally used for an array index. It contains "words" from `@array1` so how about `$word`?

Comment: So which way is best?

Comment: @Borodin You will have to loop over it for every element of array1 anyway, provided you don't want to create a hash of keys that never appear in array1. As for the variable, it's a one line loop, its a disposable one character variable.

Comment: @123: *"provided you don't want to create a hash of keys that never appear in array1"* And why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: @user145265: The *"best"* way is the one that you can read in a week's time and understand best what it's doing. It's the solution that best implies to you what it's doing. That's the reason for language words `if`, `while`, for` etc. not being `op1`, `op2`, `op3`; the language provides a framework that allows you write self-representative code. You can easily misuse it, but I suggest that you should use identifiers and language constructs that allow your code to be read as something approaching a natural language. Even assembler has stuff like `MVB` for *move byte*

Comment: @Borodin `why wouldn't you do that`, why would you want to waste space on variables you are never going to use ? Regarding reading in a weeks time, i think this is pretty clear. The fact that it actually searches for values from one array in another (which is the intention) makes it far clearer what  the end goal is. If for some reason someone is unable to understand what the ONE LINE loop does, even years in the future, then i fear they may have chosen the wrong hobby/career.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array1 instead of the hash keys:

```
for my $key (@array1) {
  my $count = $hash{$key} // 0;
  print "$key = $count\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change how you declare `%hash`

```
my %hash = map {$_ => 0} @array1;
```

This will create a hash with keys from `@array1` all initialized to zero.